# How can I make my servlet maintain / have the capability of updating the contents of my array list?

Tags: java, forms, session, servlets

In my home page, I have the following code:

```
<h2>Item 1</h2>
<p>100.00</p> 
<form action= "addtoCart" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="item1" value="1"/>
    <button value="add">Add this to cart</button>
</form>

<h2>Item 2</h2>
<p>50.00</p> 
<form action= "addtoCart" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="item2" value="2"/>
    <button type="submit" value="add">Add this to cart</button>
</form>
```

For my servlet, I have the following:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(); 
ArrayList<Product> cart = new ArrayList<Product>(); 
session.setAttribute("InCart", cart);

Product a = new Product("Item 1", 200);
Product b = new Product("Item 2", 50);

if ((request.getParameter("item1")) != null) {

    cart.add(a);
    out.println(cart.toString());


} else if ((request.getParameter("item2")) != null) {

    cart.add(b);
    out.print(cart.toString());
}
```

In my code, if I click the Add to Cart button for item 1, I get redirected to my servlet and it successfully displays the list (which currently has product a). Now if I go back to my home page and click the Add to Cart button for item 2, the servlet does not maintain the contents, it only ends up printing the list which only has product b.

My desired outcome would be that the list prints out product a + product b (since I clicked the button for item 1 and item 2). I am almost sure that it has to do with properly handling my sessions, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(); 
ArrayList<Product> cart = new ArrayList<Product>(); 
session.setAttribute("InCart", cart);
```

You are always creating a new cart object and adding it to your HttpSession.  Overwriting any existing ArrayList that was created on previous requests.

It might be better to check to see if the ArrayList called "InCart" exists in the session first and if not, then create it and add it to the HttpSession.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(); 

List<Product> cart = (List<Product>) session.getAttribute("InCart");

if (cart == null) {

    cart = new ArrayList<Product>(); 
    session.setAttribute("InCart", cart);
}
```

Comment: Your adjustments completely work in the way I want my program to run. Although I had to cast the session.getAtrtribute("InCart") into a List. Also, thank you for the welcome! I've always been a lurker here but it's my first time posting. I've noticed that my question gained negative traction, do you have any suggestions on how I can improve on posting questions?

Comment: Glad everything worked.  Added the cast to the answer for completeness.  I do not have a good answer for you on why you got down voted.  I think folks here expect everyone to do their own research here and if there is something that even remotely close to a duplicate question they down vote.  It is one of the least attractive features of S.O.  It is easy to forget that we live in an [Eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September).